# How can I re-throw a CFileException?

Tags: exception, visual-c++, mfc, try-catch

I know that I can re-throw a `CFileException` if I am inside a `catch` statement by using `throw` to bubble it up the chain.

But what about this:

```
CFile               fileRPT;
CFileException      ex;

if (!fileRPT.Open(L"SomeFile.txt", CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite, &ex))
{
    ex.ReportError();
    return;
}
```

It directly fills the `CFileException` object so I can't just use the keyword `throw` as we are not in a `catch` block.

---

If I try `throw ex` this is displayed:

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand, but you can simply `throw ex;`.

Comment: I see, `CFileException` apparently predates common best practices: Throw by value, catch by (const) reference. You'll have to throw a pointer then. I'd probably just do: `auto ex = std::make_unique<CFileException>();`, pass `ex.get()` into `CFile::Open`, and `throw ex.release();` on error.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks, or just call `AfxThrowFileException`.

Comment: `AfxThrowFileException` is a utility function, that's meant to be used in code that doesn't already have a `CFileException`. `CFile::Open` populates an existing `CFileException` object, so there's no need to construct yet another one (which is what `AfxThrowFileException` does). The `std::unique_ptr` dance is a bit tedious, since you can only throw by pointer, but also want automatic resource management.

Comment: @IInspectable When I run it in debug mode, if no error is encountered (the Open command returns true) I get an exception concerning the deleting of the ex variable on `ASSERT(pException->m_bReadyForDelete);`. I tried making a call to `ex.reset()` and it still happened. For now I reverted to `AfxThrowFileException` because I get no debug asserts.

Comment: Oh well, that's unfortunate. As I understand it, throwing by pointer introduces the issue of ownership: *Someone* will have to clean up the exception object, and that someone may not necessarily know, how to do that. I'm guessing that that's what the `bAutoDelete` argument to the base class `CException` c'tor controls, although I didn't follow how `m_bReadyForDelete` factors into all of that. Maybe a custom deleter (calling `CException::Delete`) is required for the `unique_ptr`, but at that point I'd probably just got with `AfxThrowFileException`, even if it makes a needless copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clue was in the online [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfileexception-class?view=msvc-170#cfileexception), about using [`AfxThrowFileException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/exception-processing?view=msvc-170#afxthrowfileexception).

So:

```
AfxThrowFileException(ex.m_cause, ex.m_lOsError, ex.m_strFileName);
```

---

Based on the comments I have changed to using a smart pointer:

```
auto ex = std::make_unique<CFileException>();
if (!fileRPT.Open(strFileName, CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite, ex.get()))
{
    throw ex.release();
}
```